# Android does not access xhdpi folder for tablet view

Tags: android, xml, drawable, tablet, hdpi

I have both `hdpi` and `xhdpi` folders in my res folder. However, android makes use of `hdpi` xml file for `1280 X 800` resolution of a tablet. Could it be because my xml file accesses resources which are in `drawable-hdpi` folder but not in `drawable-xhdpi` folder?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused with DPI vs screen sizes, which resolution along does not provide. You can have a XHDPI device with a small screen that is very high resolution (such as the Galaxy S3) or a MDPI or LDPI device with a very large screen (such as when you use Android on your TV).

Generally speaking, Dot per pixel = Resolution / Screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Not all android devices are set to the right density by the manufacturer, its really a hodgepodge of densities no matter what resolution you think you have, the device could still be seen by the android OS as a lower or different density than you think

if the android OS thinks your device is HDPI then it will access HDPI drawables

Comment: that doesn't solve the question. How do i make it use my xhdpi folder?
and i am using emulator

Comment: oh the emulator, try using skin  Built In: WXGA720 or one of these resolutions 2048x1536  2560x1536  2560x1600

Comment: All the resolutions wouldn't launch. The emulator is just showing up with a black screen